# How to make views have the same size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have three LinearLayouts. I want to make the width of each one of them be the same size. Each of them can be 1/3 of the total screen size. I want to do this in the XML layout file. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use `android:layout_weight=1` on each one of them to give them an equal width.